# Using Count and Rotate left

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

Q. Use RotateLeft and Count to find the number of planets detected by each method, presenting the result in a list of the form {{D, n1}, {R, n2}, {T, n3}}.

```
planets = {{Beta Pictoris B, D, {7, 1.6}}, {WASP52B, 
T, {0.453, 1.270}}, {Kepler426b, T, {1.0, 1.090}}, {CoRoT6b, 
T, {2.95, 1.166}}, {Kepler34b, R, {0.220, 0.784}}, {Kepler367b, 
R, {0.0037, 0.116}}, {Kepler200c, R, {0.0119, 0.142}}};
```

I have got this far with it;

```
new = RotateLeft[planets, {1, 4}]
new2 = new[[All, 1]]
Count[new2, T]
```

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way. Bare in mind I need to use these two functions to answer, so although I'm sure there are other ways to solve this please use Count and RotateLeft.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: "But I'm not sure if this is the correct way." There's not exactly an objectively correct way of solving this problem that actually uses `RotateLeft`. `Count` and `Map` would make more sense, and `Tally` and `RotateLeft` or `Part` would make sense, but `Count` and `RotateLeft` is definitely an X-Y problem. While I can't speak for the graders, I would hope that any solution that returns the correct form would be considered correct. Also, if you're using `Part` (as `[[]]`) then you can omit the rotate entirely: `new2=planets[[All, 2]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Tally[planets[[All, 2]]]
```

> {{D, 1}, {T, 3}, {R, 3}}

If you want the result ordered:

```
Sort @ Tally[planets[[All, 2]]]
```

> {{D, 1}, {R, 3}, {T, 3}}

If you ***have to*** use `RotateLeft`:

```
Tally[Map[First] @ RotateLeft[planets, {0, 1}]]
```

> {{D, 1}, {T, 3}, {R, 3}}

or

```
Tally[Map[First] @ Map[RotateLeft] @ planets]
```

> {{D, 1}, {T, 3}, {R, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

Using level specs and a pattern you can do it with `Count` and skip the `RotateLeft`.

```
methods = {D, T, R};

AssociationMap[Count[planets, #, {2}]&, methods]
(* <|D -> 1, T -> 3, R -> 3|> *)
```

If you do use `RotateLeft` with a level spec, you can do this rather interesting if weird thing:

```
rotated = RotateLeft[planets, {0, 1}]
(* 
{{D, {7, 1.6}, "Beta Pictoris B"}, 
 {T, {0.453, 1.27}, "WASP52B"}, 
 {T, {1., 1.09}, "Kepler426b"}, 
 {T, {2.95, 1.166}, "CoRoT6b"}, 
 {R, {0.22, 0.784}, "Kepler34b"}, 
 {R, {0.0037, 0.116}, "Kepler367b"}, 
 {R, {0.0119, 0.142}, "Kepler200c"}}
*)
tests = AssociationMap[List /* Append[___] /* Count]
(* 
<|D -> Count[{D, ___}], T -> Count[{T, ___}], R -> Count[{R, ___}]|>
*)
counts = Map[Curry[Construct][rotated], tests]
(* <|D -> 1, T -> 3, R -> 3|> *)
```

Hmm. I think I may have suffered brain damage due to excessive [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)) consumption.

Anyway, if you just want to do it in a single line of idiomatic Mathematica, here you go:

```
CountsBy[planets, Extract[{2}]]
(* <|D -> 1, T -> 3, R -> 3|> *)
```

In these circumstances, though, I find it's often best to use `Replace` instead of `Extract`, as it lets me be explicit about what the data I'm destructuring means:

```
CountsBy[planets, Replace[{name_, method_, coords_} :> method]]
(* <|D -> 1, T -> 3, R -> 3|> *)
```